# How to change default timezone settings to UTC in No SQL Booster for MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, datetime, nosql

I am saving some datetime objects in UTC in `mongodb`. I am using [nosqlbooster for mongodb](https://nosqlbooster.com/downloads). Datetime is getting saved in `UTC` timezone but nosqlbooster is showing me in my timezone. When I downloaded and used `Compass` for mongodb, so compass was showing me time in UTC only.

How can I change this settings in nosqlbooster.

Comment: In MongoDB dates are always and only stored as UTC times. There should be some settings available in nosqlbooster.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done from options:

Options -> Outpul Panel -> Display DateTime in -> UTC